# Cannot create an instance of Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter`1[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I run my application and it gets to this section of code breaks:

```
var Adapter_ = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.calibre_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
```

This is the error that it's throwing:

> System.MemberAccessException Message=Cannot create an instance of
> Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter`1[T] because
> Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Comment: 1. That is not C code. 2. Please do not post images for code but instead copy it as formatted text into the question - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) 3. Stack Overflow is an English site so please translate your question into English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is an English-only website

Comment: I think the answer below is significantly better than the 2 responses above.  I vote leave it alone as we can clearly see the problem and the solution even if the question isn't asked in English (I don't speak that language and I can deduce the meaning from the question)

Answer (score 4):

You neeed to set a type `ArrayAdapter<T>` of items in your array. Set `ArrayAdapter<string>` if it's an array of string items, for example.

```
var Adapter_ = ArrayAdapter<string>.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.calibre_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
```